Найти минимальный элемент массива Си
Нужно найти минимальный элемент в массива и вывести его. Начал изучать Си и что не получается. Ошибся, но где?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int findMin(int *arr)
{
    int count = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}


int main(void)
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,-1,-5}; 
    
    printf("Наименьшее число массива :%i", findMin(arr));

    return 0;
}


sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) работает только на массивах, а arr - указатель. Передавайте размер отдельным параметром.

Когда вы передаете массив в функцию, то он не сохраняет информацию о его размере, и sizeof(arr) вернет просто размер указателя, а не размер самого массива.
int findMin(int *arr, int size)
{
    int min = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, -1, -5}; 
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    ...
}


Ради интереса, а можно ли как-то узнать размер массива по указателю? Или указатель указывает только на первый элемент массива и не указывает на последний?

@Sopeake , все верно, указатель указывает только на первый элемент массива. Дальше, в случае изучения с++, там будет доп функция для того, чтобы узнать размер массива, но в Си - такого нет

@citn В С++ нет таких функций (которые по одному указателю определяли бы размер).

@HolyBlackCat имел в виду size()/length() у контейнеров STL
